# Azure AD auth in MVC passthrough impersonation to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

What I have:

- MVC and web api accessing an azure sql database through entity framework (don't think EF matters in this case).
- Azure AD login for the MVC app

What I want to do:

- Use the logged in Azure AD user to connect to the azure sql database (impersonate the user).

Now I know people are going to tell me don't do this because of connection pooling, etc. But this is for a small company and the web app in question will have probably 2 concurrent users at most at any given time so I am not worried about such things. The DBA wants to use individual logins to the sql server so he can setup row level security easily. Maybe there is a different way to go about setting things up, but I want to get this working if possible.

So does anyone have any idea how to go about doing this?

I tried using the following connection string:

```
Data Source=tcp:mydbinstance.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

This throws an error:

```
Failed to authenticate the user NT Authority\Anonymous Logon in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated).
Error code 0x4BC; state 10
The format of the specified domain name is invalid.
```

I've searched but can't find anything about that message that gives me any answers. And as you would expect this doesn't seem to be a thing people regularly try to do.

Comment: I have this same requirement and it seems this should be possible, because a JWT token from Azure AD could be passed along when creating the EF connection. Calling AcquireTokenAsync if necessary. I don't think that "Active Directory Integrated" is the way to go though. A connection has to be made programatically using the bearer token of the individual users.

Comment: Hi @MarkH, Did you figure out?

Comment: @CarlosGarcia Yes I did and it was a pain to setup. You'll want to call an instance of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext's AcquireTokenAsync method to get the AccessToken. You use that to set a SqlConnection's AccessToken property. The app registration requires Azure Sql Database user_impersonation Delegated permissions.

Comment: Thank you @MarkH! I have to do it with Python, so I will probably use MSAL library to get the token. By the way, you should write that as an answer - I will vote it up

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think this is going to work. Sql Azure uses <strike>integrated</strike> SQL security, and your MVC app uses claims based. One thing that should work is host the MVC site on an azure VM which is joined to your domain.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Unfortunately a VM is not an option. I think we will just use SESSION_CONTEXT for our row level security and hope that no one figures out how to spoof another user (if they did I suspect the RLS wouldn't have stopped them anyways).